# Using copy as I get an error

Tags: plotting, latex

When I try to copy a plot file as a LaTex file I get the following error,

> TeXForm of GraphicsBox[<<1>>,AspectRatio->NCache[1/GoldenRatio,0.6180339887498948`],Axes->{True,True},AxesLabel->{None,None},<<9>>,PlotRange->{{6.479922918`*^19,<<15>>},{<<1>>}},PlotRangeClipping->True,PlotRangePadding->{{Scaled[0.02`],Scaled[0.02`]},{Scaled[0.05`],Scaled[0.05`]}},Ticks->{Automatic,Automatic}] is not supported. >>

I am using Mathematica 10.3 and Windows 10. 
My goal is to place a Plot into RevteX. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `TeXForm` mainly works with code,  especially equations and other  math typesetting stuff, but not for graphics. For graphics,  exporting to EPS or PDF usually works.

Answer (score 1):

Copy as LaTex is using function `TeXForm`. From the documentation this is using AMS-LaTeX that does not support complex graphics.  It is basically used for text and formulas.  If you want to include a graphic in your LaTex then you should export the graphic in one of the may image formats the Mathematica supports and reference that in the LaTex document.

Hope this helps